# Visual Studio: JSON visualizer when debugging

Tags: visual-studio, json, visual-studio-2010, debuggervisualizer

When debugging in Visual Studio 2010 and hovering over a variable name, I'm given the option to use 3 different built-in visualizers:  Text, XML, & HTML.

*Here is an example of what I'm referring to:*

[image: Visual studio debugger visualization screenshot]

Since I'm doing more and more work with JSON based data, **is there a JSON visualizer that I can install**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may reference theses posts:

[JSON Debugger visualizer in Visual Studio 2012](http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2013/03/03/json-debugger-visualizer-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx)

[JSON Debugger Visualizer in Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/02/06/json-debugger-visualizer-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)

Answer (score 13):

Yes, use this addon on Codeplex.

[archive.org - JSON Viewer on Codeplex](https://web.archive.org/web/20170411161743/http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/)

Comment: No - it produces 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' when you click a variable and choose JSON as the visualizer. I'm using the latest version which is 1.2.

Comment: i cant find JsonViewer.dll.config

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'EPocalipse.Json.Visualizer.JsonVisualizer' to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.DialogDebuggerVisualizer'.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.DebugViewerShim.ManagedShim.DelegatedHost.CreateViewer(IntPtr hwnd, HostServicesHelper hsh, SafeProxyWrapper proxy)

Answer (score 6):

**Overtly visible disclamer:** I wrote this and I'm giving it away for free via Microsofts Visual Studio Gallery. No ads, no link to my own site or anything.

I found this thread when looking for the exact same thing but seeing that http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/ is "A visualizer for Visual Studio 2005" i felt that it was probably to outdated for my use. So I wrote a new visualizer instead (with built in jsonlint-support!). It has been tested with Visual Studio 2012 (but probably works fine for at least 2008 and 2010) and available from Microsofts [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ca9c71b0-111c-48b8-9119-3a41fa9b88ba).

Comment: can it convert a object into json string?

Comment: No, this is just a tool to preview JSON in string variables in Visual Studio. If you need to work with JSON in your own project (serializing/deserializing objects for example) you should have a look at JSON.Net. http://james.newtonking.com/json

Comment: It seems so, that site hasn't been up in a few months. I kinda abandoned this addon since it came builtin in Visual Studio 2015 (even the community edition). Nevertheless, I've uploaded the latest version I found on my computer (which was newer then the one available earlier) so hopefully it'll work if you are on an older version of visual studio.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it does work in visual studio 2010, but you have to unblock the assemblies. In explorer right click on the DLL and view properties the is a button to unblock the assembly.

Answer (score 3):

I know the question references specifically Visual Studio 2010, but at least in Visual Studio 2019, the *JSON Visualizer* is already integrated so you don't need any extension, I would say.

Just select the *JSON Visualizer* in variable's view context menu:

[image: select JSON Visualizer]

And then press the view button:

[image: view a variable containing a JSON string]